# Heroku Deployment Issue - Python version

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I have been working on a Django project that I am trying to deploy to Heroku. I've followed a tutorial from Python Crash Course. When I enter git push heroku master, I get the following as a response:

```
Counting objects: 73, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (65/65), done.
Writing objects: 100% (73/73), 26.20 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 73 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.2 (you are using Python-2.7.12, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.2).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing Python-2.7.12
remote:  !     Requested runtime (Python-2.7.12) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to fathomless-scrubland-11916.
remote:
```

When I Python --version the cmd line returns 2.7.14 which is the most up-to-date version. I feel like this error is telling me I need to use Python3 but their site says that 2.7.14 is supported as well. My runtime.txt specifies 2.7.14.

Answer (score 0):

Please try python-3.5.2 in runtime.txt
though it gives a warning it still works